# Is my solution, in my case, for nested INSERT EXEC Statement good?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

When I run the script below I get error `INSERT EXEC Statement cannot be nested`

Some info regard the stored proc:

1. Multiply connections may call stored proc **a**
2. I can't use UDF because in each proc I need to use **IDENTITY_INSERT**, **try...catch blocks**

I thought to create table with name **tmp** and instead of inserting data into temporary tables in b,c stored proces, they would insert the data in **tmp** table. To map the rows to specific connection I can add **Group** column and populate it with **@@SPID**. In the end of stored proc **a** I will remove all rows of specific **@@SPID** so it can be used with other connection.
Is this good and effective solution?

Thank you

```
create procedure a
as
begin try
    declare @tbl table(id int)
    insert into @tbl
    exec b
end try
begin catch
end catch


create procedure b
as
begin try
    declare @tbl table(id int)
    insert into @tbl
    exec c

   select * from @tbl
end try
begin catch
end catch


create procedure b
as
begin try
    declare @tbl table(id int)

    insert into @tbl(id)
    values(1)

    select * from @tbl
end try
begin catch
end catch
```

sdfdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to read Erland Sommarskog's article, [How to Share Data Between Stored Procedures](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html)

Comment: I've read this article. I can't use functions, because it doesn't allow using setting **identity_insert**. The only alternative I think I can use is **global table**, isn't it or I've missed something?

Comment: @theateist another workaround would be to return result sets as XML. However, maybe your bigger problem is your need for IDENTITY_INSERT. Why do you need it? Could we come up with some alternative solution which does not use it?

Answer (score 1):

In general I would use a session specific temp table, that way you have much less overhead managing aborted transactions and such, as it cleans itself up.

The disadvantage is that it is a tad fragile, since dependencies are invisible:

```
create procedure a
as
    set nocount on
    create table #tbl (id int)
    exec b

    set nocount off
    select * from #tbl
go

create procedure b
as
   set nocount on 

   insert into #tbl
   values(1)
   exec c

go

create procedure c
as
    set nocount on

    insert into #tbl
    values(2)

go 


exec a
```

I would usually shy away from `@@SPID` scoping, if you somehow forget to clean up you will have unexpected results.

That said: the solution you use highly depends on the problem at hand Erland's article Alex [linked](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html) specifies all the options out there.